# Explode column from csv file using Pandas

Tags: pandas, csv, explode

I have many csv files that have, in the first column, an identifier for the row and, in the second column, counts for each id. I need to expand the second column into rows within the identifier that nests the observations. However, df.explode() does not appear to work with the raw data.

Example data: [test_data.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q1lc59j2fmsdnse/test_data.csv?dl=0)

```
df = pd.read_csv('test_data.csv')
df

df.explode('count')
```

In this case, df.explode does not appear to do anything. What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `list` is a python object, and such information isn't stored in a `csv`. So when you read the file it's imported as a string `'[this, string, is, not, a, list]'`.

You can read the `csv` with `converters` to ensure it's converted to the python object.

```
import ast
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test_data.csv', converters={'count': ast.literal_eval})

df.explode('count')
#   id count
#0   A     5
#0   A     3
#0   A     0
#0   A     5
#0   A     6
#.. ..   ...
#3   D    11
#3   D     2
#3   D     1
#3   D     1
#3   D     6
```